# html form is not executing properly

Tags: javascript, html, forms

When user fill up all the fields of form and click submit then I want to show a alert dialog box, but when i call that javascript function then HTML form dont work properly. Means even i left all the input fields blank then also i can submit the form and it shows the alert box on browser. Plz help

form.html

```
 <form>
  <br>
  <input type="name"  id="name" size="40" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required><br>
   <br>
<input type="email" id="email" size="40" placeholder="your email here...." class="form-control" required><br>
   <br>
<input type="text" id="comment" size="50" placeholder="Comment..." class="form-control" required><br><br>

  <input type="submit" onclick="abc()" value="send me" class="btn custom-btn">Send me</button>
 </form>
```

JS function

```
 <script>
function abc() {
message = "<ul><li><b>Name: </b>" + document.name.value;
message += "<li><b>Email: </b>" + document.email.value;
message += "<li><b>Comment: </b>" + document.Comment.value + "</ul>";
alert('Sent Successfully..!   We will contact you shortly.'); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: you try changing `onclick="abc()"` to `onsubmit="abc()"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved, I have used this script

```
 <script>
function abc() {
    var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
    var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
    var comment=document.getElementById('comment').value;

   if(name=="" || email=="" || comment=="")
   {
    alert("Please fill all fields");
   }
   else
   {
    alert("name : "+name+"\nemail :"+email+"\ncomment :"+comment);
   }
}

function ValidateEmail(mail) 
 {
     var email=document.getElementById('email').value;

     if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email))
 {
return (true)
 }
alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
return (false)
}
</script>
```

html

```
 <form >
     <br>
     <input type="name"  id="name" size="40" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required><br>
      <br>
      <input type="email" id="email" size="40" placeholder="your email here...." class="form-control" onblur="ValidateEmail(this)" required><br>
      <br>
     <input type="text" id="comment" size="50" placeholder="Comment..." class="form-control" required><br><br>
      <button type="submit"  value="send me"class="btn" onclick="abc();">Send me</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `document.getElementById` to get the value and execute `abc()` on form submit like the following:

```js
function abc(self) {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var comment = document.getElementById('comment').value;
    var message = "<ul>";
    message = "<li><b>Name: </b>" + name + "</li>";
    message += "<li><b>Email: </b>" + email + "</li>";
    message += "<li><b>Comment: </b>" + comment + "</li>";
    message += "</ul>";
    self.innerHTML = message;
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit="return abc(this)" >
    <input type="name"  id="name" size="40" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required><br/><br/>
    <input type = "email" id="email" size="40" placeholder="your email here...." class="form-control" required><br/><br/>
    <input type = "text" id="comment" size="50" placeholder="Comment..." class="form-control" required><br/><br/>
    <input type = "submit" value="send me" class="btn custom-btn" />
</form>
```

Comment: i update code for you diffrence is abc now on form submit

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use JQuery to listen `submit` event on the form when all the form validations are passed. Then inside the submit function you can get the values of each form elements by their `id`.

```js
$('#formId').submit(function abc() {
  message = "<ul><li><b>Name: </b>" + $('#name').val();
  message += "<li><b>Email: </b>" + $('#email').val();
  message += "<li><b>Comment: </b>" + $('#comment').val() + "</ul>";
  alert('Sent Successfully..!   We will contact you shortly.' + message); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='formId'>
  <br>
  <input type="name"  id="name" size="40" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required><br>
   <br>
<input type="email" id="email" size="40" placeholder="your email here...." class="form-control" required><br>
   <br>
<input type="text" id="comment" size="50" placeholder="Comment..." class="form-control" required><br><br>

  <button type="submit" value="send me" class="btn custom-btn">Send me</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Nobody mentioned jQuery and this doesn't in any way help OP understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to write document

```js
 <script>
function abc() {
message = "<ul><li><b>Name: </b>" + name.value;
message += "<li><b>Email: </b>" + email.value;
message += "<li><b>Comment: </b>" +Comment.value + "</ul>";
alert('Sent Successfully..!   We will contact you shortly.'); 
}
</script>
```

```html
<form>
  <br>
  <input type="name"  id="name" size="40" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required><br>
   <br>
<input type="email" id="email" size="40" placeholder="your email here...." class="form-control" required><br>
   <br>
<input type="text" id="comment" size="50" placeholder="Comment..." class="form-control" required><br><br>

  <input type="submit" onclick="abc()" value="send me" class="btn custom-btn">Send me</button>
 </form>
```